# Mysql: Unable to fetch value from a select query inside a query

Tags: mysql

I have the following query. If I run it I get this error [message](http://i48.tinypic.com/28bz5m0.png).

Query-

```
SELECT account_name,ABC,date FROM entries
    LEFT JOIN accounts ON accounts.id = entries.accounts_id
    LEFT JOIN voucher ON voucher.id = entries.trans_id 
    WHERE trans_id IN ( SELECT trans_id, amount AS ABC FROM entries 
                         WHERE accounts_id='$accounts_id' AND side='C') 
    AND accounts_id!='$accounts_id' AND side='D'
    AND voucher.date between '$dateragne1' AND '$dateragne2'
```

I think the problem is with the value `ABC`. It is unable to fetch the value from the second query.

Could you please tell me how to fix this query?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT account_name, _inner.ABC, date 
  FROM 
  (
     SELECT amount AS ABC FROM entries 
       WHERE accounts_id='$accounts_id' AND side='C'
  ) AS _inner, entries
  LEFT JOIN accounts ON accounts.id = entries.accounts_id
  LEFT JOIN voucher ON voucher.id = entries.trans_id
    WHERE trans_id IN 
    ( 
      SELECT trans_id FROM entries WHERE accounts_id='$accounts_id' AND side='C'
    ) 
AND accounts_id!='$accounts_id' AND side='D'
AND voucher.date between '$dateragne1' AND '$dateragne2'`
```

**Notes:**

- Using subquery like this doesn't allow you to request a fields from it.
- Also, `IN` statement use data from only only column, not two.